# Left bit shifter in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I need to create a left bit shifter in VHDL using if then statements. I am not sure what to do from what ive already written. I've attached photos and the code below. Thanks a ton!

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkS5s.png)

[The problem im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzOvM.png)

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity shifter is
PORT ( 
            input: IN UNSIGNED (7 DOWNTO 0);
            shift_cntrl : IN UNSIGNED (1 DOWNTO 0);
            shift_out : OUT UNSIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0)
        );
        end shifter;
    
    architecture arch of shifter is
    
    begin 
    process (input, shift_cntrl)
    begin
    
    if (shift_cntrl="00") then shift_out<=input;
    
    else if (shift_cntrl="11") then shift_out<=input;
    
    else if (shift_cntrl="01") then shift_out<=input+4;
    
    else if (shift_cntrl="10") then shift_out<=input+8;
    
    end if;
    end process;
    end arch;
```

Comment: Powers of two multiplication has the advantage of setting a decimal integer literal to the length of the other operand and producing a result twice it's length. In synthesis this would be translated to shifts. `shift_out <= input * 4;` would be a shift left of two for example and the right hand expression would provide a matching element for each element of the assignment target. Provide a clear indication of the shift distances specified by shift_control (the additions don't appear valid). Correct the `else if`s to `elsif`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VHDL-2008 then you can use the sll operator to perform the shift, for example, to shift by one bit:

```
shift_out <= input sll 1;
```

Otherwise you can simply append a number of bits to the end of the input value using the ampersand, for example to shift by a single bit:

```
shift_out <= input & '0';
```

You need to be careful when doing this though as the expression on the right hand side should have the same number of bits as the signal on the left hand side. In your example, input is 8 bits and shift_out is 16 bits so you need do some zero padding as well. For a 1 bit shift you would do this:

```
 shift_out <= '0000000' & input & '0';
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is under-specified, but I believe this is what you want to do:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity shifter is
    port ( 
        input:        in std_ulogic_vector (7 downto 0);
        shift_cntrl:  in std_ulogic_vector (1 downto 0);
        shift_out:   out std_ulogic_vector (15 downto 0)
    );
end shifter;

architecture arch of shifter is
begin 
    process (input, shift_cntrl)
    begin
        if    shift_cntrl = "00" then shift_out <= x"00" & input;
        elsif shift_cntrl = "11" then shift_out <= x"00" & input;
        elsif shift_cntrl = "01" then shift_out <= x"0"  & input & x"0";
        elsif shift_cntrl = "10" then shift_out <= input & x"00";
        end if;
    end process;
end arch;
```

I have changed the interface to use "std_ulogic_vector", which should be used more often. I have not had the opportunity to test this though, because that would involve writing a test bench as well.

There are a number of problems with your code as-is, "else if" is not valid VHDL, it should be replaced with "elsif". Adding 4 to an unsigned will not perform a shift either, it will just add 4 to the value.